# SQL Formula Query | (DATEDIFF / DATEDIFF) Returning 0

Tags: sql, datediff

I have a conundrum surrounding the DATEDIFF SQL Function, essentially i have a list of customers with policies, such as insurance. I can obtain the following Details:

1. Policy End Date
2. Policy Start Date
3. Today's Date

I'm trying to extract the % of which the policy term has reached, essentially to get this i have converted the above into "Days" using the DATEDIFF function to get how many days have passed and how many days in total. I want to divide these to get the % but the output is coming in at 0

My formula, were both sides of the division work separately but not together is as below:

```
,   (DATEDIFF(DD,DATEADD(YY,-1,P.RDAT#),GETDATE()))
    /
    DATEDIFF(DD,DATEADD(YY,-1,P.RDAT#),P.Rdat#)
```

Have tried casting / converting thinking it was something do do with this but to no avail, if anyone can help that would be super.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server does integer division, so `1/2` is `0` rather than `0.5`.  I think you want:

```
(DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, P.RDAT#), GETDATE())) * 1.0 /
 DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, P.RDAT#), P.Rdat#)
```

I am not sure what the `dateadd()` is supposed to be doing.  You may be able to simplify this logic.  For that, I would recommend asking a new question with sample data and desired results.

Comment: This has worked perfectly, thanks so much...The DateAdd is a necessary evil due to the limited data within the database, essentially the RDat# is a insurance renewal date, the start date is a year before, but not within the data so have improvised :) by taking a year from it...Thanks again!